# Change wlan0 MAC Address RTL8188CUS Device Raspbian

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, router, mac-address

I was creating a router with the Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I have successfully created the router, but I wanted to change the MAC Address on wlan0. I bought the Miniature WiFi Module from ADAFruit (http://www.adafruit.com/products/814) and was wondering if it is possible to change the MAC address associated with it. I have tried using the following code:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
sudo ifup wlan0
```

or

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo macchanger -r wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0*
```

or by adding a line in /etc/network/interfaces

```
hwaddress ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

and various other combinations and attempts.

When using lsusb the device shows up as "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter". In /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf, driver=rtl1871xdrv. I am running ISC DHCP Server. Raspbian on Raspberry Pi model B.

The device works otherwise. I just want to be able to change the MAC address. I don't know if this is the problem with the device or my settings or something completely different. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is not programming question. You will have better luck asking this at http://superuser.stackexchange.com or http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. I will try at superuser. I tried at raspberrypi, but was told that was not the appropriate place either

Comment: Since your methods do work on any Ubuntu or Debian, this problem must be Raspbian specific. I think your question is really appropriate for raspberrypi site.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ifconfig wlan0 down      #Bring wifi down
macchanger -r wlan0      #Randomly generate new MAC address
ifconfig wlan0 up        #Bring wifi back up

ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | sort | awk ' {print "Ip: "$1}'      #Displays ip address
```

Use ifconfig to make sure that wlan0 is the adapter. If you put this in a script, you won't need to use sudo; other than to run the script.

Comment: Same here on a RTL8188, the driver seems to disallow changing the MAC address.